# Need cp -ax alternate for Solaris

Tags: solaris, cp, arguments, clipboard

On my Linux host; this cp command helps copy files and folders both while preserving the timestamp and permissions `cp -ax <source file/folder> <destination>`

Need similar command for SunOS solaris as the above command fails due to `illegal option -- x`

```
$ which cp
  /usr/bin/cp                                                                                             $ uname -a                                                                         
SunOS myhost 5.11 11.41.28.82.3 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

Answer (score 2):

Solaris uses `cp -p` option for this. Both `/usr/bin/cp` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/cp` have this option, according to the Oracle online man page.

Linux `cp -a` is equivalent to `-dR --preserve=all` so you might need to look up additional options for the links and recursive features.

Comment: Downvoter: Tell me where I am wrong or incomplete, and I can improve the answer.

Comment: I tried the following on Solaris but it fails:     `cp -p -dR --preserve=all test.log test.log.bkp
cp: illegal option -- d
cp: illegal option -- preserve=all
Usage: cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-P] [-z] [-@] [-/] f1 f2
       cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-P] [-z] [-@] [-/] f1 ... fn d1
       cp -r [-H|-L|-P] [-f] [-i] [-p] [-z] [-@] [-/] d1 ... dn-1 dn
       cp -R [-H|-L|-P] [-f] [-i] [-p] [-z] [-@] [-/] d1 ... dn-1 dn`

Comment: `-dR --preserve=all` are flags for the GNU cp used on Linux, not the Solaris cp.  If you want to use those flags you need to use GNU cp instead.

Comment: @Ashar. You misunderstood me. Linux `cp -a` invokes those three options as described in the Linux man page. The Oracle man page has equivalents that you can match via the descriptions. The description of -x is unclear anyway -- "stay on this file system, except for mount points"! Solaris supports -p and -R, and -x appears to merely ignore soft links across file systems. As I don't know your exact requirements, you should read your own man pages.

Comment: The Linux (GNU) option `-a` is non-standard. Solaris supports the POSIX standard way, so use `cp -pR ...`. There is no POSIX equivalent for `-x`, this looks like a useful enhancement idea for Solaris.